# Store a list of unordered pairs in java

Tags: java, data-structures

Say I have the following ordered pairs `(A, B), (A, C), (B, C) and (B, A)`.

Out of those 4 pairs, there are 3 unordered pairs.

My question is: Does java have a data structure that does NOT allow duplicates or palindromes? (`(A, B)` and `(B, A)` are the same unordered set)

`Set` removes the possibility of duplicates, but not the other part.

```
Set<Entry<Integer, Integer >> values = new HashSet<Entry<Integer, Integer >>();
```

What data structure is the best choice for this type of thing, or am I better off, just creating my own?

Comment: Set doesnt allow duplicate but not palindrome which you could check by reversing String and adding into the set for e.g.

Comment: Since when does a `List` remove the possibility of duplicates??

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm sorry, I was thinking about Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does java have a data structure that does NOT allow duplicates or palindromes?

Well Java has a number of sets - `HashSet`, for example. Those don't allow multiple *equal* values to be stored... so you just need to create a class which has the sort of equality you want. For example:

```
// Note: not null-safe. (See below.)
public final class UnorderedPair<T> {
    private final T first;
    private final T second;

    public UnorderedPair(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return first.hashCode() + second.hashCode();
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof UnorderedPair)) {
            return false;
        }

        UnorderedPair<?> otherPair = (UnorderedPair<?>) other;
        return (first.equals(otherPair.first) && second.equals(otherPair.second))
            || (first.equals(otherPair.second) && second.equals(otherPair.first));
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

Then you can just create `UnorderedPair<String>` values or whatever, and then a `Set<UnorderedPair<String>>`.

Note that the above doesn't handle null values correctly - you'd need to either validate that both `first` and `second` are non-null in the constructor, or handle possibly-null values.

Comment: Just one quick question: is the @override really necessary?

Comment: @Nilzone-: It will compile without - but I would *strongly* recommend using `@Override` a) to tell readers what you intend; b) to let the compiler check that you really are overriding a method.

Answer (score 4):

> Does java have a data structure that does NOT allow duplicates or palindromes?

Not directly.

However, you could synthesize one using a `TreeSet` and a custom `Comparator` that compared pairs in a way that has the required properties.

For example:

```
   public class Pair<T> {
      public final T left;
      public final T right; 
      ...
   }

   /**
    * Comparator that treats `(A, B)` and `(B, A)` as identical.
    */
   public class PairComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> 
              implements Comparator<Pair<T>> {
      public int compare (Pair<T> p1, Pair<T> p2) {
         T p1Small, p1Large, p2Small, p2Large;
         if (p1.left.compareTo(p1.right) <= 0) {
             p1Small = p1.left;
             p1Large = p1.right;
         } else {
             p1Small = p1.right;
             p1Large = p1.left;
         }
         if (p2.left.compareTo(p2.right) <= 0) {
             p2Small = p2.left;
             p2Large = p2.right;
         } else {
             p2Small = p2.right;
             p2Large = p2.left;
         }
         int res = p1Small.compareTo(p2Small);
         if (res == 0) {
            res = p1Large.compareTo(p2Large);
         }
         return res;
      }
   }
```

For a solution that works with `HashSet`, see Jon Skeet's answer.  However, note that you have to implement an "unnatural" flavour of `equals` to do that ... which could be problematic if you also need to test `Pair` objects using "natural" equality semantics.

Answer (score 1):

> Does java have a data structure that does NOT allow duplicates or
>   palindromes?

As other mentionned, no.

The easiest that comes to my mind is to sort each list, then simply store in a set using functional programming. Example :

```
List<List<String>> myListOfPair = new ArrayList<>();
myListOfPair.add(new ArrayList<>());
myListOfPair.add(new ArrayList<>());
myListOfPair.add(new ArrayList<>());
myListOfPair.add(new ArrayList<>());
myListOfPair.get(0).add("A");
myListOfPair.get(0).add("B");
myListOfPair.get(1).add("A");
myListOfPair.get(1).add("C");
myListOfPair.get(2).add("B");
myListOfPair.get(2).add("C");
myListOfPair.get(3).add("B");
myListOfPair.get(3).add("A");

System.out.println("Original list : " + myListOfPair);

Set<List<String>> mySet = new HashSet<>();
myListOfPair.stream().map(l -> {
    Collections.sort(l);
    return l;
}).forEach(l -> {
    mySet.add(l);
});

System.out.println("New list (HashSet) : " + mySet);
```

That would print

```
Original list : [[A, B], [A, C], [B, C], [B, A]]
New list (HashSet) : [[A, B], [B, C], [A, C]]
```

Comment: pretty neat suggestion, but how would you change this to not include duplicates?

Comment: @Nilzone- it doesn't look at the print of "New list".

Comment: We had the sublist into a set so the duplicata are automatically handled.